# What is the edifference between spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') vs spacy.load(en)

Tags: pytorch, spacy

I have seen both of these written down in Colab Notebooks, Can someone please explain the difference between them? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In spaCy v2, it was possible to use shorthand to refer to a model in some circumstances, so "en" could be the same as "en_core_web_sm".

The way this worked internally kind of relied on symlinks, which added file system state and caused issues on Windows. This caused troubleshooting problems and confusion, so it was decided the convenience of the short names wasn't worth it, and there are no short names in v3.

So if you see code using `spacy.load("en")` it's using v2. There's no meaningful difference in how it works though.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can know this without pestering the stackoverflow community?